# cannot import requests in python script running on jenkins container

Tags: python, python-2.7, jenkins

Team,
request module is not found by python script though it is installed. so is it some path I need to tell python script to look at?
I am trying to run python on jenkins container ubuntu based.

version setup from container is below

```
python --version
Python 2.7.18

pip --version
pip 20.0.2 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.8)

uname -a
Linux code-scan-coverage-pbpbl 5.4.0-65-generic #73~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 19 09:02:24 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

which python
/usr/bin/python

pip install requests
```

jenksinfile calling python script

```
sh "pip install requests && ${workspace}/src/jenkins/ci/pba/pba_coverage_scan.sh"

result = sh(script: "python ${workspace}/src/jenkins/ci/pba/api.py",returnStdout: true).trim()
```

output

```
Requirement already satisfied: requests in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (2.22.0)

+ python /home/jenkins/agent/workspace/team/api.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/team/api.py", line 2, in <module>
    import json, requests, os
ImportError: No module named requests
```

python script is

```
import json, requests, os
def stuff_api():
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had to do this, like installing python2 and then pip2 requests.

```
add-apt-repository universe
apt update && apt install python2
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py --output get-pip.py
python2 get-pip.py
pip2 --version
pip2 install requests
```